# Microsoft Dynamics SOAP Login Call using SOAP UI

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to write a simple SOAP call to login (RetrieveCrmTicketRequest) to a Cloud MS Dynamics heres the URL - https://viraj.crm.dynamics.com. I got this by signing up the free account for Microsoft.

The SOAP Msg I used for this is.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:dis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Discovery">
<soap:Header>
  </soap:Header>

   <soap:Body>
   <Execute xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Discovery'>
<Request xsi:type='RetrieveCrmTicketRequest'>

<OrganizationName>Del</OrganizationName>
<UserId>viraj.onmicrosoft.com\vbelawade</UserId>
<Password>HIDDEN.1</Password>
<AuthenticationType>2</AuthenticationType>
</Request>
</Execute>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I got the following Response.

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>
> ## header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
>
> background-color:#555555;}
>
> ## content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}-->
>
> ```
>   </style>    </head>    <body>
>   <div id="header">
>      <h1>Server Error</h1>
>   </div>
>   <div id="content">
>      <div class="content-container">
>         <fieldset>
>            <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
>            <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
>         </fieldset>
>      </div>
>   </div>    </body> </html>
> ```

What am I doing wrong here ? 
I did not use the authentication in SOAP UI as I am writing this SOAP call for logining into Dynamics through a app which does not suppose C#, Java, PHP or any other propitiatory language.

Heres my End Point : https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc

Please help this will help me get through the first point of logining into Dynamics.

Comment: as far as I know, there isn't around a working example of SOAP UI with CRM Online

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the username is wrong... viraj.onmicrosoft.com\vbelawade <-- this looks like an AD user name and password and you are using CRM online. should be something like vbwlawade@viraj.onmicrosoft.com

take a look at the source code listed here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CRM-Online-2011-WebServices-14913a16

it's for 2011, but still relevant (if not a bit too in depth).